# Remove URL trailing slash and redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help with editing .htaccess file.

1. need to remove trailing slash from URL, for example: website.com/file/ to website.com/file. Also redirect to website.com/file when typed website.com/file/
2. redirect to website.com/file, when user type website.com/file.php/ or website.com/file.php
3. resolve HTML anchor IDs like website.com/file.php#anchor to website.com/file#anchor or better website.com/file/anchor. Is that second possible?

I tried to remove .php extension from URL and now my CSS/JS files are not working. Is possible to use relative paths to link CSS/JS or just absolute?

My .htaccess file now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 https://website.com/404

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ https%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove .php extension from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas?
Are there some .htaccess "trics" used on websites?

Thanks!